# how to store redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am beginner using Redux,I want to store redux's state in my app , because whenever I refresh the page redux will reset the state .
this is my the userSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const initialState = {
    userName: null,
    userEmail: null
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setActiveUser: (state, action) => {
            state.userName = action.payload.userName
            state.userEmail = action.payload.userEmail

        },
        setUserLogOutState: state => {
            state.userName = null
            state.userEmail = null

        }
    }
});

export const { setActiveUser, setUserLogOutState } = userSlice.actions
export const selectUserName = state => state.user.userName
export const selectUserEmail = state => state.user.userEmail

export default userSlice.reducer
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userReducer from './userSlice'
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userReducer
    }
})
```

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

Signup.js

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const userName = useSelector(selectUserName)
    const userEmail = useSelector(selectUserEmail)
    const onClickButton = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        signInWithGoogle().then((result) => {
            dispatch(setActiveUser({
                name: result.user.displayName,
                email: result.user.email
            }))
        })

    }
```

So how exactly can i store the state of the user    whenever i refresh the page ?

Comment: You have to use localstorage or redux-persist.

Comment: does the createStore stores the state as well ?

Comment: You have to persist your state because it will be cleared after the page is refreshed.

Comment: oh thank you ! , but does createStore stores the state ??

Comment: Of course, the createStore method initializes the state.

Comment: it initializes the state , is it also a solution in this particular problem ?

Comment: The createStore create an Object for your reducers, like rootReducer. It will store in the memory or the browser temp cache. After you close the tab or press an F5 this state will be gone. If you want to save your actual state you have to save it into the localStorage. You can do this with localStorage.setItem("persistedState", JSON.stringify(your redux state)). On page reload you can load your saved state into the redux with localStorage.getItem("persistedState") and you have to dispatch an action that fills your redux store with your persisted state. But the redux-persist can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways. One that comes to my mind is using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
That way you can do something like:

userSlice.js:

```
const savedState = localStorage.getItem('previousState');
const initialState = savedState ? savedState  : {
  userName: null,
  userEmail: null
}
```

And then it would be initialized if the previous state was saved.
All you would need to do is update your localStorage state whenever you update your redux state.

```
localStorage.setItem('previousState', newReduxState);
```

Comment: Thank you , one question the newReduxState refers to what exactly ?

Comment: Whenever you dispatch a new action your Redux state can change. If you want to keep those changes when you close the app you need to also update your localStorage item, otherwise it would not be updated.

Comment: so what's exactly the main purpose of Redux if it cant store state without using localStorage

Comment: Well first of all, redux makes you possible to make the app reactive. Keep in mind updating the localstorage wont make your app to change, while updating the redux state will make all the components which use the redux state to check for an update.

Another thing is that lets say you only want to update the localstorage when... when the user logins. Maybe you only want the username to make something faster and then you save all of the rest in redux for your session.